# What is the best way to find an instance of a byte array while reading in a binary file using ruby?

Tags: ruby, reverse-engineering

I am reverse engineering some old database files. It's going pretty good. All the files I have worked with so far have fixed width records and the width is defined in the header. Pretty straight forward.. I know the header length, so I can start reading the file right after the header and then I know that X bytes later I get to the end of the record. If the record is 30 bytes and the header is 100 I can do something like this:

```
 file = IO.binread(path + file_name, end_of_header, end_of_file)
 read_file(file[0, 30]) #This calls a function that parses the data..
```

However, there are several tables with dynamic width records. So, one record can be 100 bytes and the next could be 20 bytes. The records are as big as the amount of text the user saved. There does not seem to be anything that notes the record length on the record..

Each record is separated by a delimiter (FEFE). I am scanning for the next delimiter and pulling the record that way, but it takes forever to read the entire file byte by byte looking for matches. Is there a better way than scanning to find the next match OR get a list of all the indexes of each occurrence of the byte array?

RUBY...

Comment: I can't think of a way to find the next delimiter without just reading bytes until you find it. However, there are a lot of different ways to read bytes from IO in Ruby, and there may very well be a faster way than the one you've found. Can you show the source of your `read_file` method?

Comment: I read the whole file in to memory with file = IO.binread(path + file_name, end_of_header, end_of_file) read_file is passed a section of what I read in.

Comment: Have you considered treating the data as a stream instead and using e.g. [`IO#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-gets) to just read until the next delimiter? I don't know if this will be faster, but it will certainly take less memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a separator for `readline`

```
file.readline(sep="FEFE")
```

or if you mean the 2 char hex string:

```
file.readline(sep="\xFE\xFE")
```

Gets you one record (including the delimiter)

Or you can pass to a code block

```
file.readlines(sep="\xFE\xFE").each{|line|...}
```